# Converting Foreach Loop to Linq and getting error

Tags: linq, foreach, linq-to-objects

I've currently got the following foreach loop:

```
List<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();
foreach (Transmission trans in Results)
{
    searchResults.Add(new SearchResult(trans));
}
return searchResults;
```

And I'd like to convert this to a Linq expression, I've tried the following which looks like it achieve the same thing in linq to me:

```
return Results.Select(x => new SearchResult(x)).ToList();
```

However when executed I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
```

I think I understand the gist of that error but the issue I have is that I'm not actually trying to convert the Transmission Objects in the Results collection to SearchResult objects but instead to return a list of SearchResult objects, a SearchResult object being intialized like so:

```
Transmission transmission = new Transmission(...);
SearchResult result = new SearchResult(trans);
```

Any help on this would be great, I've been tearing my hair out!

EDIT: As per comments here is the full method stub:

```
        public IQueryable<Transmission> Results
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

        public virtual IEnumerable<SearchResult> ResultsNetwork
    {
        get
        {
            List<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();
            foreach (Transmission trans in Results)
            {
                searchResults.Add(new SearchResult(trans));
            }
            return searchResults;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show what your method signature?  And you are not using linq to entities, or sql?  What is the rest of your stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

I get the impression that `Results` is a collection of `object`, so `Select` is defining `x` as `object`, but you want it to be `Transmission`.

Try either of these options:

```
return Results.Cast<Transmission>().Select(x => new SearchResult(x)).ToList();
return Results.OfType<Transmission>().Select(x => new SearchResult(x)).ToList();
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to guess what you are trying to cast (you need to show your method signature, as well as a blurb showing how you convert Transmissions to SearchResult)

However and easier way to do it:

```
return Results.ConvertAll(x=> new SearchResult(x));
```